# Content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for user control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls

I want to build a user control suppose MyDiv.ascx.
This control renders the div tag and do few more code behind stuff like adding few attributes etc which is not a matter of concern here.
The problem is I want text between the opening and closing tags of the user control. Eg:

The text goes here with some other HTML tags.

So when do something like this I get a parsing error while running the website. 
Also VS2008 warns me by saying "**Content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for element** MyDiv".

- **Question 1: Can I do something like this i.e. text/markup between opening
  and closing tags of a user control?**
- **Question 2: If yes, how**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you just need to apply a couple of attributes to the control:

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
[PersistChildren(true)]
public class MyDiv : UserControl
{
    ...
```

You *may* then need to override `AddedControl` - I'm not sure.

Put it this way - that's what works for the one and only user control I've ever written :)

Comment: Wow...that worked like a charm...
But...can u plz tell me how can I get that inner html as I'm not getting this kind of property..like **this.InnerHtml or this.Children**..???

Comment: You can use [ParseChildren(true, "Body")] with a property called "Body" of type string.  This will put the contents of the InnerHtml and put it into whatever property you named as your second argument in the ParseChildren annotation.

Answer (score 20):

The suggested solutions did not work for me. I found the following solutions:
Either make your user control inherit from `Panel` instead of only `UserControl`, or if you have more than one content like in my case, make your content fields be `PlaceHolder`s instead of simple `Control`s.

The `[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]` is added to avoid XHTML validation warning.

```
public partial class DrawerControl : UserControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public PlaceHolder BodyContent { get; set; }
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public PlaceHolder GripContent { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        phBodyContent.Controls.Add(BodyContent);
        phGripContent.Controls.Add(GripContent);
    }
}
```

`phBodyContent`and `phGripContent` being `PlaceHolder`s.

This way I can use my control with any content in ASPX:

```
<local:Drawer ID="ctlDrawer" runat="server">
    <BodyContent>
        <!--Insert any ASP content here-->
    </BodyContent>
    <GripContent>
        <!--Insert any ASP content here-->
    </GripContent>
</local:Drawer>
```

Comment: May be going for a Composite Control(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositecontrol.aspx) a good solution in your case. What do u say Mart?

Comment: I added more details in my answer to illustrate the flexibility of this solution. I switch to CompositeControls when I have to embed the control into an assembly with its resources for an easier distribution.

Comment: One addition I'd suggest here is to also null check the new PlaceHolder objects before adding them to phBodyContent, etc. It worked fine for me when I specified some BodyContent, but would error out if I did not.

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to create a custom control with "innerHtml".  This is what I ended up with (based partially on some of the earlier answers/comments)...

div.ascx.cs:

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Text")] //Store inner content in Text property
public partial class div : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        litText.Text = Text;  //Render it however you want
    }
}
```

div.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="div.ascx.cs" Inherits="TestApp.Controls.div" %>
<div>
    <asp:Literal ID="litText" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Test page:

```
<%@ register src="~/Controls/div.ascx" tagname="div" tagprefix="uc" %>
<uc:div ID="div1" runat="server">Test data</uc:div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this:

[ASP.Net: User control with content area, it's clearly possible but I need some details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720002/asp-net-user-control-with-content-area-its-clearly-possible-but-i-need-some-d)

Works like a charm, but I wish I could suppress the design time message, content is not allowed between opening and closing tags, but it works at run time.

```
[ParseChildren(true, "Content")]

[PersistChildren(false)]

public partial class CollapsiblePanelControl : UserControl

{

    private Control content;

    // add the content
    this.MainContent.Controls.Add(content);

    // if this is not a post back
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        // set to true;
        this.Expanded = true;
    }
}
```

The markup is like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="CollapsiblePanelMainPanel" runat="server" CssClass="collapsiblepanel">
    <asp:Panel ID="CollapsibleHeaderPanel" runat="server" CssClass="collapsibleheaderpanel">
        <asp:ImageButton ID="CollapseButton" ImageUrl="~/Images/BlueArrowDown.png" runat="server" OnClick="ExpandButton_Click" CssClass="expandbutton" /> 
        <asp:Label ID="CollapsiblePanelHeaderLabel" runat="server" Text="Collapsed" CssClass="collapsiblelabel"></asp:Label>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

And then in the client:

```
<dc:CollapsiblePanelControl ID="CheckOnMePanel" runat="server" CssClass="checkonmepanel" EnableViewState="true"
        CollapsedHeight="20px" ExpandedHeight="300px" Expanded="true" HeaderText="Check On Me Email Service" >
    <Content>
        ...[Your Content Goes Here]
    </Content>
</dc:CollapsiblePanelControl>
```

Comment: You can suppress that error message by adding this metadata to the class: `[ToolboxData("<{0}:CONTROLNAME runat=server> </{0}:CONTROLNAME>")]` (note the space between open and closing tags)

Answer (score 0):

Add a Text property to your control and linked this text property to a label run at server that will be between the opening and closing div.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to be careful, what if you put a server control in the content area...

You might just want to make a control inherit from a panel and override any methods you need to adjust? Might be easier or harder depending on what you need to customize

```
public class MyDiv : Panel
{

}
```

Comment: I can't do this I guess...bcoz it's already inheriting from UserControl class...so won't be able to inherit from other class...is their any Interface I can implement???

Comment: Panel itself inherits from UserControl, so you will still have all the UserControl stuff available to you.