# Get the value between an ASP.net user controls tags

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am wanting to create a user control which I will use for Tooltips around my site. I am wanting to call the user control from any of my .aspx pages as follows:

```
<gp:ToolTip ID="ctrlToolTip" runat="server">SOME TEXT OR HTML FOR MY TOOLTIP</gp:ToolTip>
```

Does anyone know how I can get the string in between the `<gp:tooltip>` tags from the user control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312108/content-is-not-allowed-between-the-opening-and-closing-tags-for-user-control

Comment: Thanks Cory. That was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach (LiteralControl ltrCtrl in ctrlTooltip.Controls.OfType<LiteralControl>())
{
    string text = ltrCtrl.Text;
}
```