# Wrapping user control inside another user control's tags in ascx file

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, webforms, user-controls

I've been searching for hours on this matter but, either I'm really bad at building google queries or there is not much information about this.

I'm trying to build a user control that can "wrap" other user controls inside it, exactly the same as an `<asp:Panel>` would do. Think of it as a glorified panel (actually, that's exactly what it is).

Ideally, I want to create something like this:

```
<muc:MyUserControl ID="parentControl" runat="server" etc>
    <mouc:MyOtherUserControl ID="childControl" runat="server" etc>
    </mouc>
</muc>
```

What I'm trying to build is the `parentControl` user control, and make it "read" whatever is inside it and display/format it in a certain way (actually, just put it inside one of its panels).

Maybe this is not the correct way to go, so please point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

After rendering, this would be the ideal rendered html:

```
<div id="parentControl">
    <div>
        Stuff from parent (controls, html elements, etc)
    </div>
    <div class="childWrapper">
        <div id="childControl1" class="childControl">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: I know about dynamically added controls in the `Controls()` collection of the user control. I just want to try to avoid doing it that way, since building the view state manually for all the controls I have to add can be a real pain in the ***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

Source: [here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312108/content-is-not-allowed-between-the-opening-and-closing-tags-for-user-control)

My final code (since I'm using vb.net):

**ParentControl.ascx.vb:**

```
Public Class ParentControl
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    <PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)> _
    Public Property RightContent As PlaceHolder

    Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        phRightContent.Controls.Add(Me.RightContent)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**ParentControl.ascx:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <div id="LeftContent" class="LeftContent">
        PARENT STUFF HERE
    </div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phRightContent" runat="server">
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**WebForm.ascx:**

```
<pc:ParentControl ID="ParentControl" runat="server" >
    <RightContent>
        <cc:ChildControl ID="ChildControl" runat="server" />
    </RightContent>
</pc:ParentControl>
```