# Extend the Panel class and customize how the child controls are added (C# webforms)

Tags: c#, panel, web-controls

I'm trying to make a custom Panel where the child controls are added to another panel, and this new panel is added to the custom panel instead.
For exemple, I wish that something like this:

```
<asp:CustomPanel>
    <asp:Label ID="someLabel" runat="server" />
</asp:CustomPanel>
```

To be parsed to something like this:

```
<div class="someClass">
    <div class="someOtherClass">
        <label id="someLabel"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Is it possible to create something like this usign Custom Controls or User Controls?

Comment: There should be a question in your question.

Comment: @dcidral Have you tried to use either [User control or custom control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651710(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Comment: @eugene-podskal that is what I'm trying to do, to create a custom control or a user control that can be parsed the way I described in my post. Something like the ContentPlaceHolder of the Master Pages.

Comment: @dcidral But what have you actually tried? There are a lot of tutorials on how to create custom/user controls (and even a few questions that may ask exactly what you want), so you should have at least tried to apply those instruction before asking a question. Had you not been successful, then you could have provided [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that would have shown us, that you have spent a reasonable amount of effort to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content is not allowed between the opening and closing tags for user control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312108/content-is-not-allowed-between-the-opening-and-closing-tags-for-user-control) .That may not be the exact duplicate, but it discusses a bit simpler UserControls and seems to be very close to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you @EugenePodskal . I'll try this solution. I didn't know it was possible to add ContentHolders to the custom control. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!